# scrapy list return: how to process / extract each element of a list?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, siblings

I wanted to ask how it is possible to deal with lists of extracted data within one variable. As the (xpath) selector only extracts the first .extract_first() or all of the content .extract (), I wondered, how I can iterate and extract only one element...like .extract()[i] and i=i+1... How does that have to be put?

It seems so obvious but at this point I don't understand how to make use of itemloaders, pipelines or whatever scrapy documentations provides to get this problem solved.

```
item ['author'] = sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@data-hook, "review-author")]/text()').extract_first()

item ['author'] = sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@data-hook, "review-author")]/text()').extract()[0]

item ['author'] = sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@data-hook, "review-author")]/text()').extract()[i] ... i=i+1???
```

Also if you could just point me to the correct direction, I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over list with `for` loop:

```
for author in sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@data-hook, "review-author")]/text()').extract():
    item ['author'] = author
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list you can iterate over it with a for-loop.

```
item ['author'] = sel.xpath('.//a[contains(@data-hook, "review-author")]/text()').extract()

// Using this for-loop construct instead of indices avoids off-by-one errors
// and the code won't run if the list is empty.
for element in item['author']:
    print element
    // Do whatever you want with the element.
```